# Shiny: preventing initial error messages in endpoints while conductor executes

Tags: r, shiny

I am building my first Shiny app - you can access the live version here: http://justmytwospence.shinyapps.io/StepLively/

It works fine, but you can probably see my problem as soon as you load the page. All of hte outputs hinge on a reactive conductor that takes a while to execute (its the function that actually performs a step-wise regression). Therefore, my outputs display error messages until the reactive conductor finishes executing. This only takes a few seconds, but it very annoying and unpolished.

Is there a way to schedule the execution of the reactive endpoints so that they don't execute until the reactive conductor has finished? Alternatively- but less favorably- is there a way to test for the availability of the reactive conductor and display something else when it is not available. Something along the lines of `if (reactive_conductor_function()) {blah}`. That won't work, however, because its a function.

Edit: I added an "Execute" button to completely bypass this issue, so its not evident in the app at the moment.

Comment: "Page not found" - and the relevant code would help us to help you

Comment: Using a progress bar from the experimental `shinyIncubator` package will not solve this problem, but gives the user at least some information. Here a small gist https://gist.github.com/markheckmann/8191104. It still has the problem you describe though...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Stéphane, I had moved the app to the shinapps.io platform and the link was outdated. Its hard to see the problem as it stands because I've added an Execute button that masks the panels that display the error messages. 

The code is here: https://github.com/justmytwospence/steplively

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
if(is.null(reactive_conductor_function()){return(NULL)}
#rest of your code follows
```

or

```
reactive_data <- reactive_conductor_function()
if(is.null(reactive_data)){return(NULL)}
#rest of your code follows
```

Both of these will prevent anything downstream in that code block from happening until after the reactive_conductor_function has data. I'm not sure on the first one, but I frequently use the second version of this code.

I would be able to give better advice if you could post some code examples!